# Please burninate multiple tag

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

[multiple](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/multiple) does no good and brings in [multiple](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/multiple)**!** problems.

Please burninate it.

Comment: Glad to see your declension isn't lacking. I was worried for a moment ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Agreed, it is now burninated.

[image: tag burninated]